# android multichoicemodelistener delete internal storage file

Tags: android

In my app i have a Listview where multichoicemodelistener is enabled. I want to delete the internal storage files (files that is shown in my listview) using multichoicemodelistener. But with no luck.

Here is my code

```
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {



            case R.id.list_context_delte:
                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
                for(int i = sparseBooleanArray.size() -1; i >= 0; i--)
                    context.deleteFile(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i));

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mode.finish();

                Toast.makeText(ShowListActivity.this, R.string.deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mode.finish();
        }
        return false;

    }
```

I got an Error that says: The method deleteFile(String) in the type Context is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE**
I have edited my code, so know it look like

```
 public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {         
       case R.id.list_context_delte:
                nr = 0;
                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

                for(int i = sparseBooleanArray.size() -1; i >= 0; i--)
                    if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                        String items =  getListView().getAdapter().getItem(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i)).toString(); 

                        File dir = getFilesDir();
                    File file = new File(dir, (items));
                    file.delete();
                    RowItem selecteditem = mAdapter.getItem(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i));
                    mAdapter.remove(selecteditem);
                     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(ShowListActivity.this,items+ R.string.deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                       }
                    mode.finish();


        }



        return false;

    }
```

After I press the delete button, the file(s) is gone. But when I go out of the activity and go back to the activity all the deleted files is back.
Are the files not deleted correctly from the internal storage ?
Does someone have a suggestions?

Comment: Have you investigated what .getCheckedItemPositions() delivers? And .keyAt(i) ? Please do.

Comment: I have also tried to delete the files with context.DeleteFile(items). but again with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file exists, looks like your code will delete the file.you can add a line for safety.

```
if(file.exists()){
  boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
  Log.v(TAG,"file delection is success : "+isDeleted);
}
```

I think the actual problem exists here.Its possible that file is actually deleted but you are not refreshing the listview.As soon as you delete the file,delete the item in the adapter and update the list view.Like this:

```
     for(int i = sparseBooleanArray.size() -1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                String items =  getListView().getAdapter().getItem(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i)).toString();
        File dir = getFilesDir();
        File file = new File(dir, (items));
        boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
          if(isDeleted){
              mAdapter.deleteItem(items); // create a  method in adapter which will delete the item.
              mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(ShowListActivity.this,items+ R.string.deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            }

            mode.finish();
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. But I think there is something wrong with the code, there should delete the selected files. Because when i use following code, there should be a toast shown. but the toast isn't shown. 

if (isDeleted) {
          Toast.makeText(ShowListActivity.this,items+ R.string.deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: i have moved toast above one line

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out. 
My code know look like this, and it work perfect about deleting internal storage files

```
 public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {         
       case R.id.list_context_delte:
                nr = 0;

                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

                for(int i = sparseBooleanArray.size() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                   RowItem selecteditem = mAdapter.getItem(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(i));
                   String selecteditemString = selecteditem.getFilename().toString();

                    File dir = getFilesDir();
                    File file = new File(dir, (selecteditemString));
                    file.delete();
                    mAdapter.remove(selecteditem);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                    }
                }
                    mode.finish();


        }



        return false;

    }
```